# Install glibc 11 on ubuntu precise(12.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, glibc

I have a app compiled locally with ldd version
`(Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.4) 2.15` that I need to run in a server with ldd `version 2.12`. Because it is built in QT framework and I do not have root access to install the framework or upgrade `libc.so.6`, I need to install an older glibc on my machine to compile as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host). After downloading `glibc-2.11.2.tar.gz` from [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc) an try to install it with command `./configure --prefix=/usr/oldlibc` it displays the following error :

```
/bogdan/Downloads/safe/csu/crti.o
/tmp/ccHNBWLa.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccHNBWLa.s: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
/tmp/ccHNBWLa.s: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
make[2]: *** [/home/bogdan/Downloads/safe/csu/crti.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/bogdan/Downloads/glibc-2.11/csu'
make[1]: *** [csu/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bogdan/Downloads/glibc-2.11'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What can I do to properly install `libc.so.6` ?

Comment: Build your app statically? Do not downgrade glibc like that on a running system. You could install ubuntu10.04 on a vm and build there.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I have tried that but this time I have problems intalling opencv2. I don't found any repository to have opencv2

Comment: Not mentioned in your question, but you can get the source and build it. Downgrading glibc would break whatever opencv2 you have.

Comment: Why, precisely, do you think you need to downgrade glibc? This should never be necessary.

Comment: @duskwuff, because I have a compatibility issue between what gnu c library I have on my computer and what I have on server. For the moment when I try to execute the program on server it gives me an error. I do not have access right now to server, but the error is `glibc version 15 is needed to run something`

Answer (score 0):

> I have a app compiled locally with ldd version

You are wrong in stating `ldd` version. The `ldd` is *part of* `glibc`, and it's the `glibc` version that is causing you grief. The `ldd` itself has *nothing* to do with anything here.

> `/tmp/ccHNBWLa.s: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive`

This is happening because the old `glibc-2.11` can not be built with a new `gcc` that you have on your system.

You can hack on `glibc` source and fix that problem, you can build and install older `gcc` and use *it* to build `glibc-2.11`, or you can set up a `chroot` environment with the old glibc installed in the default place.

The `chroot` solution is likely the easiest, because you can simply install prebuilt (older) packages into it.

Another "easy" alternative is to build everything in a VM.